# rename a list of files according to a text file

Tags: rename

I have a list of files in a folder, which I will like to rename according to a textfile. For example:

These are the 5 files in the folder.

```
101_T1.nii
107_T1.nii 
109_T1.nii
118_T1.nii
120_T1.nii
```

I will like to have them rename using a text file containing a list of new filenames in the same order, without the extension `.nii`:

```
n01
n02
n03
n04
n05
```

How may I go about doing so?

Comment: `ls | paste - /the/text/file | xargs -n2 mv`

Answer (score 16):

one liner, this command reads the 'list' txt and parses for each line a file.

```
for file in *.nii; do read line;  mv -v "${file}" "${line}";  done < list
```

Answer (score 3):

You could do:

```
paste OLD NEW|while read OLD NEW;do mv ${OLD} ${NEW};done
```

...where the file named "OLD" contains the old filenames and the file named "NEW" has the new matching (1:1) names.

Answer (score 0):

If your shell supports process substitution, try:

```
paste -d' ' <(ls *.nii) /path/to/textfile | xargs -n2 mv
```

or you can do it POSIXly:

```
ls *.nii | paste -d' ' - /path/to/textfile | xargs -n2 mv
```